# Filter on first letter of property

Tags: ios, swift, filter, realm

I've got a local db (Realm) with drinks. Each drink has a name.

I want to get all the drinks starting with a certain letter.

This is what I came up with:

```
let objects = realm.objects(Drank.self)
                   .filter{($0.name.characters.first)?.description == section}
```

The problem I am having now is that the objecttype I get is a 'LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection'. But I need Results.

Does anybody know a way to convert it to the correct type or maybe a different way to filter the resultset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is straight from the realm docs on sorting/filtering:

```
let sortedDogs = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("color = 'tan' AND name BEGINSWITH 'B'").sorted(byProperty: "name")
```

So to filter something you are looking for maybe something like this:

```
let objects = realm.objects(Drank.self)
               .filter("name BEGINSWITH '\(column)'")
```

A safer option proposed below by Thomas Goyne,

```
let objects = realm.objects(Drank.self)
               .filter("name BEGINSWITH %@", column)
```

Since you are now filtering data with the way the docs use you should receive a Results object

Don't be afraid to read documentation, not only will you be able to get the satisfaction of figuring it out on your own, you will also learn a bunch of other things along the way.

Comment: You could use the `hasPrefix` function too. Might be easier.

Comment: While it's presumably fine in this case, in general you'll want to use `.filter("name BEGINSWITH %@", column)` for filtering on strings because Swift's string interpolation will break when the string contains an apostrophe.